# MYSQL insert to db utf-8 string

Tags: php, mysql

I inserting data to mysql database from php 
Code:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO games_cisla (name, description, genre, date) VALUES('$name', '$desc', '1234č5678', '$release[0]' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Insert value: 1234č5678

Db value: 1234

There seems to be some problem with the encoding. But what?

Comment: What's the type of the field `genre`?

Comment: `'1234č5678, '$release[0]'` you're missing a single quote on `'1234č5678'`

Comment: And what's the problem? anyway you're missing a `'` after `'1234č5678`.

Comment: sorry guys, i edit field before posting this post. This is not problem. Problem is utf8

Comment: Check the collation of the table and columns to make sure it is set for utf-8 and not some other character set.  see `show table status;` and `show full columns from TABLENAME;` queries to see what the character sets are

Comment: Collation is utf8_general_ci